# Equation of a plane through intersection of two and parallel to other

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems

I have got two planes $$x+y+z=1$$ and $$2x+3y-z+4=0$$ . I am required to find a plane by intersection of two and parallel to $x$ axis . I think the plane parallel to $x$ axis 
so Simply $P1+kP2=0$ hence
$$x(1+2k)+y(1+3k)+z(1-k)-1+4k=0$$
and how to create a relation by which this plane is parallel to $x$ axis and with  any other given plane ?

Comment: Its normal is perpendicular to $x$-axis?

Comment: Yes I think, it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in taking the required plane to be $P_1+k P_2 = 0$ (Intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$). Since the required plane is parallel to the $x$-axis, the co-efficient of $x$ in it's equation should be $0$. $2k+1 = 0 \implies k = \frac{-1}{2}$. The required plane is:
$$
\frac{-y}{2} + \frac{3z}{2} - 3 = 0 
$$

BTW, the  $z$ co-efficient is $1-k$ and not $1-4k$.

Comment: That means if i were given another plane(instead of x axis) , I should simply compare coefficient ?

Comment: Yes, if you want a plane parallel to this, you should compare the coefficients.

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks to help me out here